# IEnumerator WaitForSeconds not working correctly during couroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to start a couroutine that triggers an animation then waits for 10 seconds and goes into another anim.

I have a simple IEnumerator that goes between 2 anim stages and has a small wait between each one.

When I run the scripts the first time it does wait 10 seconds to start (trapActivate) and then waits 10 seconds to start (trapInactivate) but the animations after that just play one after another without waiting the 10 seconds they should be waiting between anim states.

Not sure what the issue could be.
I looked up a a lot of threads of people having issues because they where starting their couritne inside their Update function but I'm not doing that so not really sure what else could be causing that.

I already tried changing the wait time and no matter how long they are after the first wait they just start playing one after another.

I can see them jumping between each other in the animator

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimateEveryNTime : MonoBehaviour
{

private Animator animator;

public void Start() {
     StartCoroutine(playAnimation());
     Debug.Log("Couroutine");
     animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}
 
public IEnumerator playAnimation() {
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
 
     // Insert your Play Animations here
     animator.SetTrigger("trapActivate");
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
     animator.SetTrigger("trapInactive");
 
}
}
```

Here is a pic of my animator layout:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq80L.png)

Comment: have you tried a `Boolean` instead of a `Trigger`? The thing with `Triggers` is it can stack so having this component multiple times in your scene might cause the behavior you describe

Comment: Does the controller have only 2 transitions? Does each transition only have 1 condition and the condition is a trigger? Is this script the only way to change these triggers? If yes all, does the animation state keep jumping after disabling this script?

Comment: `public void Start() {
     StartCoroutine(playAnimation());
     Debug.Log("Couroutine");
     animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}` 
recommend that you write something like this:
`public void Start() {animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
     StartCoroutine(playAnimation());
     Debug.Log("Couroutine");
}`

Comment: Hi @shingo Yes I only have 2 transitions both going back and forth between the idle state into the Sandworm state here is a pic of my animator layout:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq80L.png

Answer (score 0):

Your image shows the type of the two parameters is **Bool** not **Trigger**. The interest thing is `SetTrigger` can also work for **Bool** parameters and set their values to true. So you need delete them and create new parameters with the type **Trigger** and same names.